# How to fix this ambiguous?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter-3

I get a database error:

Error Number: 1052
Column 'title' in where clause is ambiguous
SELECT * FROM `insp_people`, `editors_pick`, `video_upload` WHERE `title` LIKE '%a%' ESCAPE '!'

This is the model:

```
public function getSearch($keyword) {

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('insp_people, editors_pick, video_upload');
$this->db->like('title', $keyword);
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
return $query->result();
}  
}
```

This is the controller:

```
$this->load->model('search_model');  

$this->load->model('inspiringpeoples_model');  
$this->load->model('editorspick_model');  
$this->load->model('uploadvideos_model');  

$data = $this->inspiringpeoples_model->getPosts();  
$data = $this->editorspick_model->getPosts();  
$data = $this->uploadvideos_model->getPosts();    


$keyword = $this->input->post('search');  
$data['results'] = $this->search_model->getSearch($keyword);  

$data['title'] = "Search Results";  

$this->load->view('partials/header1', $data);  
$this->load->view('search_result', $data);  
$this->load->view('partials/footer');
```

I expect the search result to show from these three tables

Comment: to paraphrase the error message, mysql said, which `title` column are you referring to? is it from `insp_people` table? or `editors_pick` table? or is it from `video_upload` table? you need to tell mysql which specific `title` column

Comment: Don't use evil SELECT *. Instead name (and qualify) the columns you actually want returned

Comment: to elaborate what Strawberry said, its much better to add the actual columns that you really want. not only for clarity and you save a bit of memory by just picking what data you really need (do you really need all the columns?) but you eliminate overwriting same column names, eg. if those three columns has `created_at` date, you'll only get once since they are converted into array with keys and you can only have one (keys are unique). then you'll be getting wrong `created_at` values (or false positives)

Comment: Can you tell me, In which table you are having column named as `title`.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$this->db->like('title', $keyword);
```

to

```
$this->db->like('editors_pick.`title`', $keyword); 
or 
$this->db->like('insp_people.`title`', $keyword); 
or 
$this->db->like('video_upload.`title`', $keyword);
```

Comment: put a tick in between

Comment: when i change to this, it gives me null results

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't any idea about PHP. But I understand that error is because of presence of column `title` in more than one table that you are using.

I would suggest something like below.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM insp_people ip, editors_pick ep, video_upload vp
 WHERE XX.title LIKE '%a%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Here XX will be one of the alias (ip, ep, vp) you have given to tables in query. Use that table alias on whose column you want to filter data on.

Hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: but it gives a null result

Comment: You can first execute query in database manually, and then debug query for results.
Or it might be a slight possibility that there is no data for that filter.

Comment: there are data present in the database..idk why its still not working

Comment: Can you give sample data and query your are using ?